# Getting a count of records between two joined tables in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

Forgive my noobness, as this question seems like it should be easy, but I've tried everything I can find for help getting `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` functions to work for my query, with no luck.

Here's my basic goal

- Get the count of issues caused by each project over a time range
- Columns: count of issues caused by each project, project IDs

Data

- Database has "issues" and "projects"
- The issues view does not link directly to projects, but instead relies on a bridge column that I have to join to
- Projects don't have a link to issues that they caused

---

### Here's the basics of what I've tried, and I'm getting error at the bottom

```
Select issues.issue_ID, project.project_ID

From Issues

Left outer join on bridge_ISSUES_to_PROJECT_source

on bridge_ISSUES_to_PROJECT_source.issue_ID=issues.issue_ID

Left outer join on Projects

on bridge_ISSUES_to_PROJECT_source.project_ID=project.project.ID

Group by project.project_ID
```

**Error**:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Issues.Issue_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your selection of the issue_id column with the COUNT() function: i.e.,

`SELECT COUNT(issues.issue_ID) AS CountOfIssues` ....

EDIT: Depending on the needs of your query, you might also need to add the DISTINCT keyword:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT issues.issue_ID) AS CountOfDistinctIssues` ....

Answer (score 0):

in this query issue_id is not in group by clause so you want to add it there but it seems that u wanted to count issues on basis of project then use count function with issue_id like count(issue_d),because with group by you have to put all fields in group by clause which you want to get in result or you have to use any aggregate function with these fields.